# Discord.Py Not Sending My Message In Discord

Tags: python, discord.py

I want my bot to say a certain line of code depending on what day it is. However, this is causing issues as the bot isn't even writing anything in Discord.

```
async def schedule(ctx):
    if x.strftime == "Wednesday":
        await ctx.send(f""" Today is {x.strftime}. Today is a half day.

Today's Schedule:

Block 1: 7:25 - 8:25

Block 2: 8:30 - 9:30

Block 3: 9:35 - 10:35

Block 4: 10:40 - 11:40""")

    elif x.strftime == "Monday" or x.strftime == "Tuesday" or x.strftime == "Thursday" or x.strftime == "Friday":
        await ctx.send(f""" Today is {x.strftime}. Today is a full day.

Today's Schedule:

Block 1: 7:25 - 8:50

Block 2: 8:55 - 10:15

Block 3: 10:20 - 12:25

Block 4: 12:33 - 1:55""")

    elif x.strftime == "Saturday" or x.strftime == "Sunday":
        await ctx.send(f"Today is {x.strftime}. No school today.")
```

Comment: Where is `x` defined? Are you getting any traceback? Try the solution I provided and see if that works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime

@client.command()  # Change client to whatever you're using
async def schedule(ctx):
    day = datetime.now().strftime("%A")
    if day == "Wednesday":
        await ctx.send(f"Today is {day}. Today is a half day.\n**Today's Schedule**"
                       f"Block 1: 7:25 - 8:25\nBlock 2: 8:30 - 9:30\nBlock 3: 9:35 - 10:35\n"
                       f"Block 4: 10:40 - 11:40")
    elif day == "Saturday" or day == "Sunday":
        await ctx.send(f"Today is {day}. No school today.")
    else:
        await ctx.send(f"Today is {day}. Today is a full day.\n**Today's Schedule**\n"
                       f"Block 1: 7:25 - 8:50\nBlock 2: 8:55 - 10:15\nBlock 3: 10:20 - 12:25\nBlock 4: 12:33 - 1:55")
```